# Views Slideshow Continuous Pager

Tags: views, paging, javascript

I'm in need of a little help here. I've recently begun my first website (ncpbc.us) and I began with building a Slideshow on my front page. However, the content that feeds into the slideshow uses nodequeue and will hold potentially hundreds of articles. Right now the queue holds 10 articles. The problem I'm having is that the slideshow pager only shows 5 thumbnails at a time and any new content simply makes the oldest content drop off. I'm trying to find a way that allows the user to advance the pager to the next set of 5 thumbnails.

Examples of this are at yahoo.com and http://joomlakave.com/joomla-modules/responsive-news- slider-like-yahoo. How would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: You need to provide more information, What are you using for building the slideshow ? the links is broken

Answer (score 0):

The link in the question is not working but after searching in google about the link I come across [this page](http://joomlakave.com/demo/index.php/module/responsive-yahoo-style-featured-article-news-slider)

If your looking for something like this then the best way will be to install [view module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [views Slideshow module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

View Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content that can appear in a view. to create a slideshow with thumbnails please check [the video](http://buildamodule.com/video/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7-building-a-slideshow-using-views-slideshow-how-to-create-a-pager-of-thumbnail-images-in-views-slideshow#viewing)